# missing parameter error even though i declared a parameter

Tags: c++

I made a program it causes error

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct numtag
{
    long num;
    char tag[60];
};

numtag *fibotag(long,long i=0,(numtag fibo[]){(numtag){0,"0"},(numtag){1,"1"}});

int main()
{
    unsigned long n;
    cout<<"Num: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<fibotag(n)[n-1].num;
};

numtag *fibotag(long n,long i,numtag fibo[])
{
    //some stuff
    return fibo;
}
```

I actually declared a parameter.

**error list:**

```cpp
10  31  D:\c++\fibo demo.cpp    [Error] expected identifier before '(' token
10  46  D:\c++\fibo demo.cpp    [Error] expected ')' before '{' token
10  31  D:\c++\fibo demo.cpp    [Error] default argument missing for parameter 3 of 'numtag* fibotag(long int, long int, int (*)(numtag*))'
10  27  D:\c++\fibo demo.cpp    [Note] ...following parameter 2 which has a default argument
D:\c++\fibo demo.cpp    In function 'numtag* fibotag(long int, long int, int (*)(numtag*))':
10  78  D:\c++\fibo demo.cpp    [Error] expected ';' before '}' token
10  78  D:\c++\fibo demo.cpp    [Warning] no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
D:\c++\fibo demo.cpp    At global scope:
10  79  D:\c++\fibo demo.cpp    [Error] expected unqualified-id before ')' token
```

It is actually a function to make a struct that have nth fibonacci number and its primality

Comment: I haven't tried to figure out what this code is supposed to do, but superficially it looks like the argument `fibo` is supposed to have a default value? If so, make it simpler with overloading: `numtag *fibotag(long n, long i, numtag *fibo) { /* whatever */ } numtag *fibotag(long n, long i = 0) { numtag dflt[] = { { 0, "0" }, { 1, "1" }}; return fibotag(n, i, dflt);`

Comment: A `long fibo[]` parameter is the same as `long*`. Even if that were the correct syntax, you can't convert a braced initializer list of `numtag` into a `long*`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh sorry. But even if i change long to numtag, it causes errors. I editted the question. 

Edit: This causes more errors than before

Comment: I highly recommend making a `typedef` for function pointers and array syntaxes.  Simplifies function parameters.

Comment: @JRBros Yes, that's because this is all very wrong (the syntax is wrong, and you can't convert a braced initializer list to any type of pointer). It would be very helpful for answering if you could explain what you're trying to accomplish with that parameter.

Comment: You could declare a default array like this: `static numtag def[] = { {0, "0"}, {1, "1"} };` and then use that as the default argument value, as in: `numtag *fibotag(long, long i=0, numtag fibo[] = def);`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Doesn't your overload end up returning the address of a local array?

Comment: @AdrianMole — maybe. <g>

Comment: I'm trying to make an array initializer in a function declaration

Comment: @JRBros That's your imagined (and non-working) solution to whatever it is you want to accomplish. What is the purpose of that parameter? If you want to pass two `numtags`, pass a `std::pair<numtag>`, or any other structure that contains two of them except an array.